# Azure cli, "az keyvault secret set" to set localDB connection string errors in powershell due to Parenthesis (localDB)

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault, azure-cli

In powershell,

Using `az keyvault secret set` to set the localdb connection string as a key vault secret fails because of the closing parenthesis ")" that precedes the "\\".

`az keyvault secret set --name ConnectionString-messaging --vault-name kvtemptest --value "server=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDb;database=messaging;trusted_connection=yes;Pooling=false;"`

the error I get is

> \MSSQLLocalDb was unexpected at this time.

Tried the below too

(backtick) but same results
`az keyvault secret set --name ConnectionString-bwalk-messaging --vault-name kvsamtemptest --value "server=(LocalDb)`\MSSQLLocalDb;database=Bwalk_Messaging;trusted_connection=yes;Pooling=false;"
`

(doubling the braces)
`az keyvault secret set --name ConnectionString-bwalk-messaging --vault-name kvsamtemptest --value "server=((LocalDb))`\MSSQLLocalDb;database=Bwalk_Messaging;trusted_connection=yes;Pooling=false;"`

*the command works gr8 in git bash console*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`az --% az keyvault secret set --name ConnectionString-messaging --vault-name kvtemptest --value "server=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDb;database=messaging;trusted_connection=yes;Pooling=false;"` should work.

That is mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively?tabs=powershell%2Cpowershell2#use-quotation-marks-in-parameters and powershell documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.3#the-stop-parsing-token

Comment: Perfect,  "az --% keyvault secret set" worked ! - Thanks